Why does "regina" primarily mean "filia regis" and only secondarily mean a queen?
Du Cange gives this for the primary definition of regina:

Regis filia : nam is olim titulus attributus Regum filiabus. Scribit enim Suidas ex Aristotele, apud Cyprios, Regum filios ἄναϰτας appellatos, ut filias ἀνάσσας. Servius ad hæc Virgilii ex 1. Æneid.

and the secondary definition of regina:

Regis uxor: Conventus apud Andelaum ann. 587

Why does regina primarily mean daughter of a king and only secondarily a queen?

Why not? If you're thinking the meaning should be closer to that in some modern languages, you're looking at it the wrong way round. It seems that you expected the opposite roles. Why so? I don't think I quite understand what you're asking for yet.

@JoonasIlmavirta If regina is the feminine form of rex, then it would seem the primary meaning of regina is a "female rex" (not daughter).

But regina is not the feminine form of rex: (1) If you check e.g. the L&S entry, you see that many meanings of regina and rex do not match. (2) What you link to says that regina is the feminine form of the putative adjective reginus, "related to rex". This is a substantial difference.

Regina comes from rex by the same route that christina (or cognate christiana) come from christus. Or at least that's one theory.

It doesn't.
Or at least, you'd need more evidence than the ordering of entries in Du Cange in order to reach that conclusion. It's an outlier among dictionaries: the sense "daughter of a king" is listed later than "queen" in Lewis and Short, the Oxford Latin Dictionary, and Gaffiot's dictionary. Rēgīna has made it into the Thesaurus Linguae Latinae, which starts out its definitions by saying

I -ae sunt feminae (contumeliose de viro sub B2): A strictius c. respectu status regalis; -ae sunt: 1 gentis externae vel non definitae, sc. quae ita vocantur: a quia nexu quodam cum rege coniunctae sunt; significantur: α quaelibet feminae domus regiae (sc. quibus est necessitudo regia vel varia vel incerta, non definita; exempla selecta post Ov.)

It can refer to various female persons related to a king, but I don't see any reason for declaring "filia regis" the primary meaning. Du Cange's "nam is olim titulus attributus Regum filiabus" also doesn't strictly speaking say that; maybe Du Cange started with this definition just because he thought that information would be more useful to his Latin-speaking readers than the information that "regina" can refer to the wife of a king or to a reigning queen (which anyone with a basic familiarity with Latin would probably already know).

@richardIII: That's just a wild guess: I was thinking that if you assume that a reader will look up a word in a dictionary when they're not sure what it means, that might justify putting less familiar definitions first in the context of a monolingual dictionary: pretty much anyone who can read the sentence "nam is olim titulus attributus Regum filiabus" will probably already be familiar with the usage of "regina" to refer to a queen. Whatever Du Cange's motivation was, it seems to have been peculiar to him.

My dictionary (Pinkster) gives "queen" as its primary meaning. For princess, it says poetical or post-classical. Lewis & Short also seem to list "princess" only under transferred senses. I actually don't remember seeing it used for princess, while I can think of several examples where it means queen. Du Cange wrote in the 17th century?
